# CSP - React webpack, styled-component, mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, content-security-policy, emotion

I followed this [article](https://medium.com/@nrshahri/csp-cra-324dd83fe5ff) to add CSP to my react application, it works, however when using the MUI and styled-component, the styles injected by them don't work, and I couldn't find any solution that isn't using Next.js SSR.

Here is my config-overrides.js file:

```js
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('csp-html-webpack-plugin');

const cspConfigPolicy = {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'base-uri': "'self'",
  'object-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': ["'self'"],
  'style-src': ["'self'"],
  'img-src': ["'self'"],
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin),
};
```

I also encountered this [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2363) that had no solution that works for the client side

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could add the error messages you encounter.

The most likely reason is that the components you have included add inline styles, which is not allowed by your policy. You would have to either add 'unsafe-inline' to style-src, replace the components, add nonces if the components allow it, or add hashes if only a limited set of styles are used. It is not advisable to add 'unsafe-inline', but it is not very bad for styles if other parts of your CSP is strict, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues with CSP and emotion/mui in next.js

As far as I can tell you basically have to use a hash with your inline mui stuff and a nonce with the server side (you can't use a nonce client side as it has to be unique for each page load).

I have found this library that seems to help but so far no joy implementing it

@next-safe/middleware | [docs](https://next-safe-middleware.vercel.app/)